# Why does the image not appear?

Tags: graphics

I'm using `IEEEtran` to format an article, and I wanted to include an image. I included the `graphicx` and `hyperref` packages, and used the following code, like normal, to include an image.

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3in]{fetch}
\caption{Pipeline: Fetch Instruction}
\label{fig:fetch}
\end{figure}
```

What appears, however, is this:

[image: Example]

`Fetch.png` is a file in the directory, and if I remove it, pdflatex errors instead of producing an output. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the `draft` document option?

Comment: Sean, I included the image for you. You have now over 10rep so you can do it now by yourself as well.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have the `draft` option enabled, most likely as class option, which makes `graphicx` to display images like this. Load `graphicx` with the `final` option to overwrite this. Note that options of the class are global and are passed to all packages, but can still be overwritten by explicit package options.

Comment: This was it. Silly me!

Comment: Oh man you saved me!!!

Comment: Thanks a million! Happened to me as well, but for the Springer template. Thanks to all the great publisher for documenting their templates extensively!

Answer (score 0):

It happened the same to me.  In my case I was defining the folder to get the pictures on top of the document through the command:  \graphicspath{ {./images/} }. But when I was asking the picture to be put in the document ,I was again specifying the folder, so I removed the folder and it worked.