# includegraphics - inserting png image leads to blank picture

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the image not appear?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/why-does-the-image-not-appear)

I am in a bit of a predicament as I try to include two PNG formatted pictures in one of my homework exercises. The following code has always worked for me without any problems:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{gst}
```

The only difference is that i recently switched from Exherbo GNU/Linux to Ubuntu GNU/Linux. Different scaling or trying out DVI-mode did not do any good.

I use the package graphicx in the following way:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
```

The program compiles without errors (with *pdflatex*) but when I take a look at the PDF the images have the right dimensions but are blank.

I have read [some other questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflate)  about this but did not find any conclusive answer for my problem. As stated above i tried DVI-mode (converting my picture to eps) and re-labeling the name of the file (from gst to gst.png).

What might be the problem causing this misbehaviour?

**UPDATE:** Mr. Scharrers comment pointed me into the right direction - the draft option for the documentclass has to be deactivated.

Comment: Are they are completely blank or is the file name written inside a framed box? (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11004/2975)). You normally don't need to give the `pdftex` option. The package is intelligent enough to figure the driver out by itself. Try also to include a different PNG as test.

Comment: Alternatively (if you like the draft option for the black markings of overfull boxes, but still want to see the images) you could add a `final` option to the `graphicx` package, which overrides the default set by `\documentclass[draft]`.