# Latex does not read figure file

Tags: graphics, pdf, pdftex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the image not appear?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/why-does-the-image-not-appear)

I have a LaTeX file, which I compile with `pdflatex` and I have put some figure with the command

```
\resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{\includegraphics{DrifterPicture/Flux_Total.png}}
```

`pdflatex` did not report any error at compilation but if the file is absent then it reports an error in the log.

The strange thing is that the figure is not shown in the resulting .pdf file. Instead the path to the figure is shown. I have checked that the figure file is ok and that the problem persist if instead of .png I use .pdf.

Comment: Don't use the draft option. (Or use the final option for graphicx or the graphics itself).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). Also, you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it), or hit Ctrl + K.

Comment: Any reason for using `\resizebox` instead of `\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{...}`?

Answer (score 4):

Using the draft option for either `\documentclass[draft]{...}` or `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` will cause printing of a boxed filename (of appropriate size).

From the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) (p 8):

> **`draft`** suppress all the ‘special’ features. In particular graphics ﬁles are not included (but they are still read for size info) just the
>   filename is printed in a box of the correct size.

Removing it should display the image, or using the `final` option:

```
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
```

> **`final`** The opposite of `draft`. Useful to over-ride a global draft option speciﬁed in the `\documentclass` command.