# Latex not showing pictures

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the image not appear?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/why-does-the-image-not-appear)

i am trying to solve my situation with pics here, I am using MUNI template fithesis2, and I have a problem, that including eps picture goes well, but there in none in the final pdf... i will show you the weird thing happening to me...

I have simply this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,draft]{fithesis2} 

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/upstream.pdf}
\caption{Upstream coverage}
\label{Upstream coverage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I compile it with this :

```
pdflatex --shell-escape thesis.tex
```

and I am getting this:

[image]

I am trying to solve it for few hours now and seem to have o solution :(
please somebody take a look, maybe its obvious I have no experience with latex

Comment: did you try \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/upstream} without ".pdf" ?

Comment: Remove `[draft]` option from the `\documentclass`.  You will get images. Also remove `pdftex` option from `graphicx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With draft option many (or all?) classes and packages don't include pictures but a 'dummy picture' with the same size and the file name.

If you omit the draft option you should see your image.

Comment: i have to be a blind man :( sry for such a stupid question people and thx for solution :)