# Path file appearing in an image when using includegraphics

Tags: graphics

I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[]{home/me/Music/MSc/Thesis/genbank.png}
\caption{The growth of genbank}\label{fig:name}
\end{figure}
```

But a blank box appears with the path to the file. Why is this?

Other questions on this site have had paths with special characters, and removing them has solved the problem. However, I don't have any special characters in mine. My packages list is:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newcounter{qcounter}
\let\centering\relax
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{name}{system}{definition}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you got `draft` among the `documentclass` options? Edit: If so, remove it, what you're seeing is one of the effects. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/why-does-the-image-not-appear

Comment: can you also put '%' immediately after music or remove line break there? and temove extension if you are using pdflatex

Comment: @percusse - no I have {article} in the documentclass options

Comment: Do you receive any error message or warning when you compile your file? In which folder is your main file?

Comment: @Ludovic C - the main file is in the same folder as the .png file. interestingly the compiler says it cannot find the file. that's with the extended path or not.

Comment: To include graphics even when having `draft` as a  `\documentclas` options, specify `final` as an option to `graphicx`. I.e. `\usepackage[final]{graphicx}`. (I realize that your problem may be due to something else, I just added this comment for others reading this question.)

Comment: even when I go into the texmaker Latex menu and select use the wizard to insert a picture by browsing the .png file, it still says file not found. this makes no sense as the wizard can find it.

Comment: I have it - the .png file I am using had been converted from a .gif. it seems this is a bad conversion as the compiler says it "is not a .PNG file". tried with another .png and it worked fine. thanks for all your help guys