# Including graphics in beamer document

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am preparing slides for a presentation and would like to add some figures, but whenever I try to include graphics, I get the following result:

[image: Including graphics in beamer]

That is, instead of the image that is supposed to be included, a box with the relative path to the image is displayed. The same error also results when I move the image to the same directory as the LaTex file.

Comment: It means that either your `\includegraphics` command is erroneous or the image is not there. Try without the file extension

Comment: Do you have the `draft` option loaded anywhere? Perhaps in `\documentclass[...,draft,...]{beamer}`, or with `\usepackage[draft]{includegraphics}`?

Comment: Related: [Placeholder for figure/`\includegraphics`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44195/5764)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why does the image not appear?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11004/5764)